# Force audio output to USB for Alarm Clock

Tags: software-compatibility, raspbian-buster

I tried to force audio to audio jack with `amixer cset numid=3 1` or using the `raspi-config` which works for other applications like audacity, vlc and other multimedia software except for the alarm clock `alarm-clock-applet` https://github.com/joh/alarm-clock , Which I am using for a project. I tried removing pulseaudio to avoid conflict but yet no success.

The alarm clock plays audio only via HDMI. I am using the new Raspian Buster. The Alarm Clock do not work properly on previous Raspbian.

I need help to get audio out via USB Audio PnP Sound Device or default audio jack. If it will be possible to modify the settings of the App which I am still trying to find out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to play the audio out for the mean time using VLC Media Player by adding this custom command

`vlc --vout none /path/to/alarm.mp3`

on the **Alert** Start Application Box. Which works very well while I keep trying the default to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

wrote a quick script for this

https://github.com/Skarlett/pi-alarm

If someone could link the details to getting audio to play through the raspberry pi audio jack, you need `omxplayer` to use it via bash. (probably some header files somewhere included for programmatic use). You'll want to reboot after you install it.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in $(seq 60)
do
    # echo $i
    omxplayer default.mp3 > /dev/null
done
```

As for a general solution for all applications? I think they all link back to having this application and its libraries, but I'd have to check up with you on that.

If you want to actually use the script solution - then you would want to hook this up to cronjobs

Comment: Thanks @Skarlett although I am not sure how to apply that with script I am working with. I have updated my question.